# QPushButton resize animation

Tags: qt, animation, resize, qpushbutton

I want to animate a QPushButton resize, is there a way to know when the button will be resized and what will be the final size so i can set the final value for the animation?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use: void QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event).

Comment: but from the doc i read that when resizeEvent is called the button already has the final geometry...

Comment: Who sets the button size? If it is out of your control, I don't think you can predict the size.

Comment: I think you're not telling us what really happens. Why is the button being resized? Is the button's size managed by a layout?

Comment: Ok, the button is in a vertical Layout, what i want to do is, when i hide another button in that Layout, animate the adjusting processs

Comment: Use [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) and animate the [`maximumHeight`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumHeight-prop) (or `maximumWith`, or `maximumSize`, which ever suits your needs) property.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at the Qt4 documents show a class QPropertyAnimation that can animate properties of widgets. Below is example code in qt documents itself that shows you can animate geometry and control initial and final values.

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(myWidget, "geometry");
animation->setDuration(10000);
animation->setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
animation->setEndValue(QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));
animation->start();
```

Check if it works for you.